# Try two download links without user interaction in Javascript or HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

My problem is as follows:

I serve a webpage to clients that contains two different download links to the same file. I want the client(!) to test both without manually clicking both links (I still present them both as a fail safe). Can this be done with javascript or html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is making an HTTP `HEAD` request and look at the status code. The status code tells you whether the resource is available, while a `HEAD` request does not fetch the resource contents itself.

This can be done with AJAX, depending on your framework.

E.g. with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ type: "HEAD",
         url: "download_url",
         complete: function(xhr) {
             if(xhr.status === 200) { /* is  available */ }
             else                   { /* not available */ }
         }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `location = "some URL"` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="providerSrc" onerror="this.src=fallbackSrc" onabort="this.src=fallbackSrc" />
```

Customized to your needs of course...